# In Drupal 8, how to automatically create a term in a specific vocabulary from the field present in node/add page?

Tags: 8, entities, taxonomy-terms

[image: term does not automatically gets created in a specific vocabulary from the node/add page]

Steps to reproduce -

- Create two new vocabularies at - `SITE/admin/structure/taxonomy/add`
- Add them as fields to the article content type. Set number of values to be unlimited, set form display to `Autocomplete (tags style)`
- The new vocab fields do not work like the Tags field

Could you help me learn how to automatically create a term in a specific vocabulary from the field present in node/add page?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to a colleague, I found the setting I had to use.

1. Go to - `SITE/admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/node.article.field_vocab_a_tag`
2. Check - `Create referenced entities if they don't already exist`

[image]

Comment: This works for drupal 8 too.